# Prevent CSS drop-down menu from extending beyond screen to the right

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, menu, flyout

I have a horizontal CSS drop-down menu in the header of my site. The menu is floated right in the header also. I am having a problem where when you mouseover the menu and you get the drop downs, if the dropdowns have sub menus that have sub menus, the menus begin to fly completely off screen to the right to where you can't see them and you get a horizontal scroll bar. This menu is created using list items like this (I have removed a Ton of items for brevity):

```
<nav id="main-menu"  role="navigation">   
   <div class="menu-navigation-container">
      <ul class="menu">         
         <li class="last expanded">
            <a href="/content/clients" title="Clients">Clients</a>
            <ul class="menu">
               <li class="first expanded">
                  <a href="/content/information-technology-client" title="IT Client Services">Information Technology</a>
                  <ul class="menu">
                     <li class="first expanded">
                        <a href="/content/enterprise-applications-client" title="Client Enterprise Applications">Enterprise Applications</a>
                        <ul class="menu">
                           <li class="first leaf"><a href="/content/oracle-client" title="Oracle Client Services">Oracle</a></li>
                           <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/peoplesoft-client" title="PeopleSoft Client Services">PeopleSoft</a></li>
                           <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/sap-client" title="SAP Client Services">SAP</a></li>
                           <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/lawson-client" title="Lawson Cilent Services">Lawson</a></li>
                           <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/hyperion-client" title="Customer Relationship Management Client Services">Hyperion</a></li>
                           <li class="leaf"><a href="/content/jd-edwards-client" title="JD Edwards Client Services">JD Edwards</a></li>                               
                        </ul>
                     </li>                     
                  </ul>
               </li>               
            </ul>
         </li>
      </ul>
   </div>
   <div class="clear"></div>
</nav>
<!-- end main-menu -->
```

So basically when you get to "Enterprise Applications" that menu is flying off the screen so you can't even see it. I have limited control over the HTML of the menu, as it is generated by the system. I cannot create additional ID's or classes. I can only work with what I have shown here. I CAN however add jQuery to a custom file to address this. Can anyone think of any jQuery (or just plain vanilla javaScript for that matter) that might be able to prevent the list items from flying off the screen? Also, this is an intranet app, so unfortunately I can't send you to a demo. Oh and I do have access to the external CSS file so I can add additional CSS, I just can't add/edit the ID's and classes of the menu itself.

THANKS

Answer (score 1):

I ended up just doing this and it seems to work.

```
$('#main-menu li').mouseenter(function() {
  //make sure menu does not fly off the right of the screen
  if ($(this).children('ul').offset().left + 200 > $(window).width()) {       
    $(this).children('ul').css('right', 180);          
  } 
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Possibly use jQuery to scroll when you hover over the dropdowns?

```
                             |
                             V
<li class="leaf" onHover="$(this).scroll();"><a href="/content/jd-edwards-client" title="JD Edwards Client Services">JD Edwards</a></li>
```